# one.com domain email SMTP request not working from render.com server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm running an Express JS server on [render.com](https://www.render.com) that is responsible for firing SMTP call to an email service. The email service is hosted on [one.com](https://www.one.com) (with a custom domain).

I'm using [nodemailer](https://www.nodemailer.com/) to handle my SMTP call, which looks like this:

```js
app.post("/send-mail", validate(schema), (req, res) => {
  console.log("sending email...");
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST,
    port: process.env.PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL_LOGIN,
      pass: process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL_PASS,
    },
  });
```

This works just fine when running the Express JS server locally - I am successfully receiving the test email. But once I do the same from [Render.com](https://www.render.com) I get a timeout error:

```
Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:776:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Not sure what's the problem. Should try to transfer the domain to another domain provider or is the problem with [Render.com](https://www.render.com)?

I tried running the Express JS server on Render.com and expected that the SMTP call would be successful just as it is when firing from localhost. The settings are exactly the same but I get two different results.

Comment: There's probably a firewall blocking it. Render.com may do this to prevent spammers from running on their servers.

Comment: ok is there a way to ask render.com to not block it?

Comment: I don't know, ask them. But it seems unlikely -- if you could do it, so could the spammers.

Comment: Are you using a paid or free account? You might need to pay.

Comment: I'm using free. So you're 100% sure Render.com is blocking any outgoing calls on free tier?

Comment: No, I'm not. Something is blocking it. It could be render.com blocking outgoing, or one.com blocking incoming.

Comment: But the incoming blocking would be unusual, unless one.com has had a problem with spam coming from render.com and this was their chosen solution.

Comment: do you know any alternative services that may solve both issues?  I just want to make a "contact me" form on my website and I want to fire SMTP calls via the node server. I'm only using one.com cause it came up first on google

Comment: It's probably *not* one.com. Instead of all this guessing, contact tech support and find out. Regardless, this isn't a programming question, it's off-topic here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257112/discussion-between-sebastian-meckovski-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by implementing a different SMTP provider, instead of nodemailer I used sendgrid.com and all works well now.